# Gradients are None when trying to implement GradCam

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to implement **GradCam** like this [Keras GradCam Tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/).

I made a reduced version of it below. No matter what I do, my gradients are `None`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras as K
import numpy as np

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 12))
x = K.applications.MobileNetV2(input_shape=(224, 224, 12),
                               include_top=False,
                               weights=None)(inputs)
x = K.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = K.layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = K.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
x = K.layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = K.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, x)

img_array = np.random.rand(1, 224, 224, 12).astype(np.float32)

grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
    [model.inputs], [model.layers[0].output, model.output]
)

image = np.random.rand(1, 224, 224, 12).astype(np.float32)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    (convOutputs, predictions) = grad_model(image)

    loss = predictions[:, tf.argmax(predictions[0])]

grads = tape.gradient(loss, convOutputs)

print(grads)
```

```
None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for getting the `None` value is because you're computing the gradient w.r.t the `input` layer. Here is one simplistic solution of the above cases:

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 12))
x = K.applications.MobileNetV2(input_tensor=inputs,
                               include_top=False,
                               weights=None)
x = K.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x.output)
x = K.layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = K.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu')(x)
x = K.layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = K.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, x)

img_array = np.random.rand(1, 224, 224, 12).astype(np.float32)

grad_model = tf.keras.models.Model(
    [model.inputs], [model.layers[1].output, model.output]
)

model.layers[0].output, model.layers[1].output
(<KerasTensor: shape=(None, 224, 224, 12) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'input_63')>,
 <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 112, 112, 32) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'Conv1')>)
```

Here, we're using `layer[1]`. Now can get the gradients of input w.r.t this.

```
image = np.random.rand(1, 224, 224, 12).astype(np.float32) 

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    (convOutputs, predictions) = grad_model(tf.cast(image, tf.float32))
    loss = predictions[:, tf.argmax(predictions[0])]

grads = tape.gradient(loss, convOutputs)
print(grads) 

tf.Tensor(
[[[[ 0.0000000e+00 -1.4619777e-16 -5.2771450e-17 ... -0.0000000e+00
     0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00]
   [-7.5641491e-17  0.0000000e+00 -0.0000000e+00 ... -0.0000000e+00
    -1.1224229e-16  0.0000000e+00]
   [-5.8784695e-17  1.0889748e-18  1.9431665e-16 ...  0.0000000e+00
     0.0000000e+00  0.0000000e+00]
   ...
```